# Is there a pattern in the complex roots of the Sine Integral $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, roots

I was working with the [Sine Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$ and found it has an infinite number of complex roots mirrored in all four quadrants. In the first quadrant these start with:

$$
11.9303627666221643518173848082 + 6.01119131213006773157261708415 \cdot i\\
24.7070169417149873195705173033 + 7.37455299482618861728760608970 \cdot i\\
37.3725098362278317680187364308 + 8.17692229518364269643530815855 \cdot i\\
49.9976565288211086812290841074 + 8.74796328051411644007205709150 \cdot i\\
\cdots
$$

Below is an extended plot of these roots in the first quadrant ($z=x+iy$):

[image]

and it appears the roots all lie on a log-shaped curve. After some attempts, the curve $y=2\log(x)+\frac12\,\log(2\,\pi)$ offers a pretty decent fit:

[image]

Q: Obviously, the above fitting is just some guess work of mine, but got curious whether anything more is known about the pattern of these roots. Searched the web extensively, however nothing comes up. Grateful for any reference and/or any steers on how to find the exact curve (if it exists) the roots reside on.

Comment: This is a nice observation

Comment: I think $x = 2\log x + 2\log (\pi /2) + o(1)$ and the sequence of the real parts is asymptotic to $4\pi n$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: @Gary. I did not see your comment since typing. This is a very good approximation. I wonder what is the very tiny term I am missing.

Comment: When @Gary says something, listen. Open your eyes, your ears and your brain as much as you can. Cheers :-)

Comment: Of course I meant $y=$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a heuristic consideration. From the [asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.ii) of $\operatorname{Si}$ we may infer that
$$
\operatorname{Si}\left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right) \approx \frac{\pi }{2} - \frac{2}{z}\cos \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)
$$
for large values of $z$. Thus the roots of $\operatorname{Si}\left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)$ are approximately the roots of
$$
\frac{\pi }{4}z = \cos \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right).
$$
Taking real and imaginary parts and approximating the hyperbolic functions by exponentials, we arrive at the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 {\rm e}^{y/2} \displaystyle\cos \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}x, \\[1ex] 
 {\rm e}^{y/2} \displaystyle\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right) = - \frac{\pi }{2}y, \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
with $z=x+\mathrm{i}y$. Taking the square sum of these equations yields
$$
{\rm e}^y = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{4}(x^2  + y^2 ),
$$
which has the approximate solution
$$
y \approx 2\log x + 2\log (\pi /2).
$$
Applying this in the second equation, we get
$$
\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right) \approx  - \frac{y}{x} \Longrightarrow x \approx 4\pi k + 2\arcsin \left( { - \frac{y}{x}} \right) \approx 4\pi k - \frac{{4\log x}}{x},
$$
with $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. The last equation is solved approximately by
$$\boxed{
x_k \approx 4\pi k - \frac{{\log k}}{{\pi k}}.}
$$
The corresponding imaginary part is then
$$\boxed{
y_k \approx 2\log x_k + 2\log (\pi /2).}
$$

Comment: I am working the problem too and I am confirming numerically the $2\log(\pi/2)$

Comment: Just look at the numbers ! Funny, isn't it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you!

Comment: I have the strange feeling that, may be, we are not very far away from a generalized Lambert function

Comment: Gary and Claude, many thanks for your great answers. Did some numerical checks and the asymptotic for the k-th zero works brilliantly. An additional observation: since the exponential integral $\mathrm{Ei}(z/2)$ is closely related to $\mathrm{Si}(z/2)$, I found that it has exactly the same asymptotic for its k-th complex root ($\mu_k$) , but now with the real and imaginary parts swapped, i.e.: ${\mu_k} = 
\ln \! \left(4 \pi  k \right)+2 \ln \! \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\mathrm{i} \left(4 \pi  k -\frac{\ln \! \left(k \right)}{\pi  k}\right)$

Comment: Oops. That should have been: $2\ln \! \left(4 \pi  k \right)$

Comment: @Gary. From new calculations, $\pi$ is back again !

Answer (score 20):

In a comment, I wrote *"This a nice observetion"*. I am totally wrong since it is $\color{red}{\text{remarkable}}$ !

Without any preconceived idea, I performed, using extremely high accuracy, the calculations for the first $2000$ roots and then, based on your work, used the model
$$y=a\log(x)+b$$

The results of the linear regression are
$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.9989369 & 0.0000806 & \{1.9987789,1.9990949\} \\
 b & 0.9130792 & 0.0007409 & \{0.9116262,0.9145323\} \\
\end{array}$$

For this regression, $R^2=0.9999999657$

These numbers are so close to your expression that you can probably conjecture it.

But, for a quick check, computing the $5000^{\text{nd}}$ root
$$x=63435.038198600614034283457758965563050039115269153,\cdots$$
$$y=23.018708803640584372540630832612830290071615109658,\cdots$$

$$2\log(x)+\frac12\,\log(2\,\pi)=23.03448181$$ shows that, probably, a very tiny correction would be required.

Using for $x$ an estimate of $4 k \pi$, using your formula for the $5000^{\text{nd}}$ root, Newton iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 62831.8530717959+24.4016677711\, i \\
 1 & 62831.8527501440+23.3938122064\, i \\
 2 & 62831.8524664822+23.0360195052\, i \\
 3 & 62831.8524045073+22.9999299632\, i \\
 4 & 62831.8524033580+22.9996004068\, i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
which is quite spectacular.

So, at least for large values of $k$, the  $k^{\text{th}}$ root of

$$\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)=0$$ is
$$z_{(k)} \sim 4 \pi  k+i \log \left(16 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{5/2} k^2\right)$$

**Edit**

Assuming that for large values of $k$, the solution is given by
$$x_k=4k\pi \quad \quad y_k=2\log(x_k)+a\quad\quad z_k=x_k+i\, y_k$$ consider the equation
$$f_k(a)=\Bigg[\Re\left(\text{Si}\left(\frac{z_k}{2}\right)\right)\Bigg]^2+\Bigg[\Im\left(\text{Si}\left(\frac{z_k}{2}\right)\right)\Bigg]^2$$ which is numerically solved using Newton method starting with
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi)\right)$$
Using $k=10^n$, the results are eloquent
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_{10^n} \\
 1  & 0.90145748249383053660\\
 2  & 0.90313659211589139775\\
 3  & 0.90316500566623502304\\
 4  & 0.90316540531377253466\\
 5  & 0.90316541046509332494\\
 6  & 0.90316541052815491646\\
 7  & 0.90316541052890101619\\
 8  & 0.90316541052890963203\\
 9  & 0.90316541052890973083\\
 10 & 0.90316541052890973083\\
 11 & 0.90316541052890973084\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This number is also identified by the $ISC$ as $2 \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

**Update**

After @Gary's answer, let
$$x_k=4 \pi  k-\frac{\log (k)}{\alpha \, k}\quad \quad y_k=2\log(x_k)+2 \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\quad\quad z_k=x_k+i\, y_k$$  and compute $\alpha$ with $k=5^n$ starting with $\alpha_0=2$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \alpha_{5^n} \\
 1 &1.40577  \\
 2 &1.94402 \\
 3 &2.22709 \\
 4 &2.40189\\
 5 &2.52059  \\
 6 &2.60646  \\
 7 &2.67146\\
 8 &2.72269  \\
 9 &2.76164 \\
 10 &2.82973  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using as an empirical model
$$\alpha_{5^n}=a-\frac b{c+5^n}$$ the fit is almost perfect $(R^2=0.999987)$ and the parameters are
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & \color{red}{3.16500} & 0.01670 & \{\color{red}{3.12551,3.20448\}} \\
 b & 4.05097 & 0.16182 & \{3.66833,4.43362\} \\
 c & 1.30543 & 0.07768 & \{1.12174,1.48912\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for this very nice answer! Note that user @Gary made a small tweak to my guess and used: $y=2\log x + 2\log (\pi /2) + o(1)$ instead. When I plug in the x-value of the 5000-th root, we now get: y=23.018708692... which very close to the real value.

Comment: @Agno. Notice that the two numbers are very close to eachother..  Compute the mean : $$\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \log (2 \pi )\right)=0.911052$$ and compare to the coefficient $b$ of the linear regression. This is a very nice problem (I am still working around it).

Comment: I will provide an explanation for my approximation tomorrow. I did not just make up that alternative constant.

Comment: @Gary. I am sure that it is more than justified. I shall wait for it. Thanks & cheers